# C Program is not executing printf at the end

Tags: c, visual-studio, printf

I'm just doing a tiny exercise for school and i'm stuck with the scanf function. 
If i'm running this code, everything just works fine at the beginning, but as soon as all 5 scanf's are done, it just stops working and exits without printing that printf at the end. Where's the problem on this?

Now here comes the Code(I code in visual studio 2017 on Windows 10):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char name[50];
    char gender[1];
    float wage = 0;
    int age = 0;
    int height = 0;

    printf("\nInput Name: ");
    scanf(" %s", name);

    printf("\nInput Gender (m/f): ");
    scanf(" %c", &gender);

    printf("\nInput Monthly Wage: ");
    scanf(" %d", &wage);

    printf("\nInput Age: ");
    scanf(" %d", &age);

    printf("\nInput height in cm: ");
    scanf(" %d", &height);


    printf("\nNAME: %s\nGENDER: %c\nWAGE %d\AGE: %d\nSIZE: %d", name, gender, wage, age, height);

    return 0;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Since your function `return`s before the call to `getchar` is reached, it's probably just that you don't get a chance to observe it.

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &gender);` invokes *undefined behavior*, you are passing a `char**`when `scanf` expects a `char*`

Comment: Newlines (`\n`) are more effective at the end of texts. Also flushing might help. And see comment by Govind.

Comment: Using `scanf()` on potentially malformed input (a.k.a. user input) without checking the return code to see if you've actually *read* a value. Refusing to parse further.

Answer (score 1):

There're many problems with your code, let's discuss them one by one :

**Problem 1** :

```
scanf(" %c", &gender);
```

here you're using `&gender` that's the problem. You've declared gender as a character array not as a variable so in `scanf` statement you've to pass the address of first element of array, so instead of `&gender` just use `gender` or `&gender[0]`. 
If you haven't learnt about pointers and addresses then go to this link:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLZp6LMUKI3cc7pgGsasm2_

Also you're taking only one character as an input then you don't need array for this. Just use `char gender;` instead of `char gender[];`

**Problem 2** :

```
scanf(" %d", &wage);
```

You've declared wage as float, so use `%f` instead of `%d`.

**Problem 3** :

```
printf("\nNAME: %s\nGENDER: %c\nWAGE %d\AGE: %d\nSIZE: %d", name, gender, wage, age, height);
```

here look at `%d\AGE`

```
\A
```

will give a warning as it seems to be an unknown escape sequence to the compiler. It's actually a typo by your side you missed \n.

So finally replace your problems with the code lines below :

```
char gender;

scanf("%f", &wage);

printf("\nNAME: %s\nGENDER: %c\nWAGE %f\nAGE: %d\nSIZE: %d", name, gender, wage, age, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your code.

While gender has been pointed out, the simple fix is to declare it as a variable.

```
char gender;
... // Do stuff
scanf("%c", &gender);
```

Wage is a float, and unless you want to declare it as an int, try

```
float wage;
... // Do stuff
scanf("%f", &wage);
```

Finally, the printf is missing a proper new line, but that may not be the problem.

Instead of

```
printf("\nNAME: %s\nGENDER: %c\nWAGE %d\AGE: %d\nSIZE: %d", name, gender, wage, age, height);
```

Try

```
printf("\nNAME: %s\nGENDER: %c\nWAGE %f\nAGE: %d\nSIZE: %d", name, gender, wage, age, height);
```

Also, the `getchar()` will have no effect since it happens after the return. anything after a return statement will have no effect.

I could very well be missing other errors, but making suggested changes should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that lead to undefined behaviour or "unexpected" things, and you should have got compiler warnings for that (if not, turn them on).

First, `gender` should be defined as `char gender;` if you want to write `scanf(" %c", &gender);` later.

Second, `wage` is of type `float` such that `scanf` and `printf` require format specifier `%f` (and not `%d`).

Third, you have "unreachable code", since your `getchar` comes after the `return 0`-statement.

Fourth, not an error/warning but just to notice, `printf` might wait for a new line before flushing its buffer to the console. So write

```
char gender;
...
scanf(" %f", &wage);
...
printf("\nNAME: %s\nGENDER: %c\nWAGE %f\AGE: %d\nSIZE: %d\n", name, gender, wage, age, height);
...
getchar();
return 0;
```